# Restrict file browsing in Wygwam / CKEditor

Tags: wygwam, channel-form

Is there a way to show only files belonging to the current EE user in CKEDitor file browser?

Failing that, can I remove the delete option from the context menu in the CKEDitor file browser to prevent different users from deleting each others files?

Failing both of those - is there an alternative that is better suited to multi-user use (i.e. one that fulfills my first option).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try this plugin: **https://github.com/pixelandtonic/wygwam_upload_tags**

You'll have to change the path in your file settings to include {member_id}